# Website automatically minifies? CSS changes wont appear

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a big problem on my website. 
When i am making changes to the CSS files nothing changes on the website.
It looks like my site is using a other CSS file u can see it here:

[image]

My website is using that CSS file while this CSS file is the correct one:

http://quasarwheels.com/wp-content/themes/gilbertson/style.css

I did include this in my header for getting the CSS file

```
    <head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title><?php bloginfo(‘name’); ?></title>
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/favicon.png">
    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="<?php bloginfo( 'url' ); ?>/favicon.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo THEME_URL;?>/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<?php if(is_singular('frame')) {?>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo THEME_URL?>/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo THEME_URL?>/css/bike-builder.css" />
    <?php }?>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://quasarwheels.com/wp-content/themes/gilbertson/style.css" />
    <!--[if IE]>
        <style type="text/css"> #mtb, #rac, #rat, #track, #rct, #rcc{   margin-top: -55%!important;}</style>
    <![endif]-->
        <?php wp_enqueue_script("jquery"); ?>

        <?php wp_head(); ?>
    </head>
```

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Have you got any more CSS links in your header?

Comment: Did you change the correct file ? Did you upload it to the server ? Did you refresh the cache ?

Comment: You've got links to three other stylesheets in your header: bootstrap, font-awesome and bike-builder. The minified styles you're talking about at the top of your question are the Bootstrap ones. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @Dre i cleared my cache 100 times, even other machines and incognitomode.

Comment: You've got some kind of BWP minification plugin at play. If you inspect the head *in your browser* (not your file) you'll see that the links are being modified, so that they point to minified files in your plugin directory. Check your plugin settings, or deactivate it altogether.

Answer (score 1):

If you inspect your page *in the browser* (not the `header.php` file) you'll see your links are being modified:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://quasarwheels.com/wp-content/themes/gilbertson/A.bootstrap,,_css,,_bootstrap.min.css+style.css,Mcc.KscEqGi0LS.css.pagespeed.cf.vgQu4bgNvt.css">
```

You can also see that several of the other stylesheets are coming from a plugin called *BWP Minify.* It looks like this plugin is minifying your stylesheets automatically, so you need to check the plugin settings and see if it needs refreshing or deactivating.

WordPress *doesn't* perform CSS minification out-of-the-box, so it's either coming from a plugin or your theme: in this instance it looks like the BWP plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure you have uploaded the correct CSS file, flush your wordpress theme's cache / site cache to force the new file to be parsed and minified.

Answer (score 0):

Move the

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://quasarwheels.com/wp-content/themes/gilbertson/style.css" />
```

link to the top of the css links so it is rendered first.

Comment: If it's rendered first any subsequent stylesheets may override the styles within.

Comment: From the looks of it, that's what he wants?

Comment: That's not how I read his question: it sounds like his CSS is being automatically minified and not reflecting the changes he's making. Loading his stylesheet first doesn't address the minification problem, plus he may encounter other problems if his styles are unexpectedly overridden by other stylesheets. The order rules are applied is important, and affects *which* rules are applied, hence you (usually) want to load your custom rules *after* things like Bootstrap, so they have priority.